# Is it possible to create a virtual Windows mic driver to replace trigger word

Tags: windows, audio, driver, wdk

I want to develop my driver based on this Microsoft base code: https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-driver-samples/tree/master/audio/sysvad

My idea is:

(1) when user says to computer: `robert, what is weather today?`

(2) Then the voice is captured by mic array driver A and send to my application.

(3) My application will change the voice to: `Alexa, what is weather today.` And send it to a virtual driver.

(4) The virtual driver captures the voice and send it to Alexa application.

(5) Alexa responses.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

I think so,

you will need to also develop your own digital assistant using [bot framework](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-virtual-assistant-introduction?view=azure-bot-service-4.0)
also in your driver, you will need to support [MVA](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/audio/voice-activation-mva)